# CSS Refactoring : SASS Mixins vs Multiple class

Tags: css, sass

I'm working on a Rails project, using HAML / SASS, and
I'm currently trying to refactor my CSS code. Maybe it's just a matter of taste, but I'd like to have
your thoughts on two different approaches :
do you usually use multiple CSS classes, or do you prefer using mixins ?
Are there any performance issues using one or another ?
Do some of you use both ? If so, how do you split your code ?

For instance :

**Multiple classes**

```
// index.html
<div id="box1" class="rectangle rounded red"></div>
<div id="box2" class="rectangle square green"></div>

// style.css.sass
.rounded
    // ...
.square
    // ...
.red
    // ...
.green
    // ...
```

**Mixins**

```
// index.html
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>

// style.css.sass
@mixin square
    // ...
@mixin rounded
    // ...
@mixin red
    // ...
@mixin green
    // ...

#box1
    // Some properties
    // ...
    @include rounded
    @include red

#box2
    // Some properties
    // ...
    @include square
    @include green
```

Comment: SO is not a good place to ask questions that are subjective.  Performance can easily be determined by running a benchmark with your A and B.  Be aware that your first approach ties the element to its presentation (it's a green box with rounded corners) rather than its purpose (it's the most recent comments listing).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the second one is faster because the browser see less blocks of codes

with this fact that ID selector is more faster than class selector I go with second

Edit :

Also the first one is hard to read and maintain

Comment: u should read this one http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

Answer (score -1):

The correct way of doing that is [extends](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend).

index.html

```
<div id="box1" class="rectangle rounded red"></div>
<div id="box2" class="rectangle square green"></div>
```

style.css.sass

```
.rounded
    // ...
.square
    // ...
.red
    // ...
.green
    // ...

#box1
  @extend .rounded
  @extend .red

#box2
  @extend .square
  @extend .red
```

You can prevent those classes from appearing in CSS by [replacing the dot with percent](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders).